Сохранение/Загрузка модели Keras с lambda слоями
Изучая Keras, столкнулся с примером, где используется предварительно обученная на ImageNet модель VGG16.
conv_base = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(
    weights="imagenet",
    include_top=False
)

conv_base.trainable = False

data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
        layers.RandomZoom(0.2)
    ]
)

inputs = keras.Input(batch_size=32, shape=(180, 180, 3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x)
x = conv_base(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(256)(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-5),
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

Далее мы задаем обратный вызов для сохранения лучшего результата и обучаем.
callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath="fine_tuning.keras",
        save_best_only=True,
        monitor="val_loss"
    )
]

history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    callbacks=callbacks
)

Ошибка возникает на этапе сохранения.
TypeError: Cannot serialize object Ellipsis of type <class 'ellipsis'>. To be serializable, a class must implement the `get_config()` method.

Проблема кроется в слое keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x). Я нашёл информацию, что имеет смысл использовать lambda-слой. Поэтому сделал вот так и обучение/сохранение проходят успешно:
x = layers.Lambda(lambda x: keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x))(x)

Но в этом случае я получаю ошибку при загрузке:
test_model = keras.models.load_model("fine_tuning.keras")

ValueError: The `{arg_name}` of this `Lambda` layer is a Python lambda. Deserializing it is unsafe. If you trust the source of the config artifact, you can override this error by passing `safe_mode=False` to `from_config()`, or calling `keras.config.enable_unsafe_deserialization().

Далее, я попробовал добавить safe_mode=False, но получаю это:
test_model = keras.models.load_model("fine_tuning.keras", safe_mode=False)

NotImplementedError: Exception encountered when calling Lambda.call().

We could not automatically infer the shape of the Lambda's output. Please specify the `output_shape` argument for this Lambda layer.

Arguments received by Lambda.call():
  • args=('<KerasTensor shape=(32, 180, 180, 3), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_123>',)
  • kwargs={'mask': 'None'}

Я пробовал задать Lambda-слою форму выходных данных, но либо я это делаю не правильно, либо не работает в принципе и получаю всё ту же ошибку.
Мучаюсь с этим второй день, очень хочется разобраться, что не так и как вообще сохранять/загружать модели с подобными слоями.
Я знаю, что в старой версии Keras это работало, но хочется использовать и изучать новую.
